# Typescript: Type Guard with string literal type

Tags: typescript

If I have the following code:

```
interface A {
    foo: string
}

interface B extends A {
    foo: "bar"
}

interface C extends A {
    foo: "baz"
}

interface D ...
```

namely, one interface and a number of other interfaces that extend the original, but fix a specific property of the original to a single string literal, is it possible for me to design a type guard for interfaces that extend the original by comparing against this property in a generic way? Something like the following:

```
function isExtensionOfA<T extends A>(obj: A): obj is T {
    return (obj.foo === T.foo.literal_value)
}
```

Comment: A type guard needs to be something that can be executed at runtime, and I'm unaware of any way to get a literal from a type to be a value at runtime

Comment: @jcalz yes thank you! this isn't the answer I was hoping for (was hoping for more from TS), but this is definitely the correct answer to my question

Comment: I assume there's some other props in your interfaces (otherwise `B` would be any object of the form `{foo: "bar"}`); do you mind if I add those to the code in the question?  Otherwise I need a preamble in my answer about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript's static type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) when TypeScript is compiled to JavaScript, so the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `T` will not exist at runtime.  That means there's no "`T.foo`" to speak of for you to check at runtime.  If you want to check a value at runtime you'll need to actually provide such a value.

Here's one possible approach, where you explicitly pass in the `foo` value you're checking against:

```
function isExtensionOfA<T extends A>(
  obj: A,
  foo: T["foo"]
): obj is T {
  return (obj.foo === foo);
}
```

And you can see that it "works":

```
function test(obj: A) {
  if (isExtensionOfA<B>(obj, "bar")) {
    obj.bProp.toFixed() // okay
  } else if (isExtensionOfA<C>(obj, "baz")) {
    obj.cProp.toUpperCase() // okay
  } else if (isExtensionOfA<D>(obj, "qux")) {
    obj.dProp // okay
  }
}
```

where the [scare quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes) are due to the following big problem with this approach:

```
test({ foo: "bar" }); // okay at compile time, but:
//  RUNTIME ERROR! obj.bProp is undefined
```

You can see that `{foo: "bar"}` was accepted by `test()` even though it's not a `B`. That's because types in TypeScript are [structural](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) (based on the shape of the data) and not [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system) (based on the *name* or *declaration*). When you write `T extends A` it means "`T` has a shape compatible with `A`" so all you know is that it has a `foo` property of type `string`.  It does not mean "`T` is one of the interfaces I explicitly declared as extending `A`".  So `T` can be all sorts of types other than `B`, `C` or `D`, including anonymous types like the type of the object literal `{foo: "bar"}`.

Oops.

---

If you really want to limit something to some enumerated set of interfaces, you're going to have to define this type explicitly as a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types):

```
type ExplicitA = B | C | D // | ...
```

And once you have that you could write `isExtensionOfA()` so that it restricts its input to `ExplicitA` objects:

```
function isExtensionOfA<K extends ExplicitA["foo"]>(
  obj: ExplicitA,
  foo: K
): obj is Extract<ExplicitA, { foo: K }> {
  return (obj.foo === foo);
}
```

and now I'm using [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to filter `ExplicitA` to just the union member corresponding to the `foo` value passed in.  Now we can make our `test()` function use it without even needing to manually specify the type arguments:

```
function test(obj: ExplicitA) {
  if (isExtensionOfA(obj, "bar")) {
    obj.bProp.toFixed() // okay
  } else if (isExtensionOfA(obj, "baz")) {
    obj.cProp.toUpperCase() // okay
  } else if (isExtensionOfA(obj, "qux")) {
    obj.dProp // okay
  }
}
```

And now the compiler will complain about calling `test()` with some anonymous type that happens to be compatible with `A`:

```
test({ foo: "bar" }); // error at compile time
```

So, that's safe, and it all "works". Uh oh, scare quotes again.

---

The problem is that we've now gone through a lot of extra effort to do something TypeScript does natively.  The type `ExplicitA` is a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) where `foo` is the *discriminant* property. We don't need a separate `isExtensionOfA()` [user-defined type guard function]https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).  We can just check the discriminant property directly:

```
function test(obj: ExplicitA) {
  if (obj.foo === "bar") {
    obj.bProp.toFixed() // okay
  } else if (obj.foo === "baz") {
    obj.cProp.toUpperCase() // okay
  } else {
    obj.dProp // okay
  }
}
```

So you probably want to just use a discriminated union to start with.  That implies your `A` interface might not be necessary (unless there are other base properties you want to inherit), and you can rename `A` to be the union:

```
interface B {
  foo: "bar"
  bProp: number;
}

interface C {
  foo: "baz"
  cProp: string;
}

interface D {
  foo: "qux"
  dProp: boolean
}

type A = B | C | D // | ...

function test(obj: A) {
  if (obj.foo === "bar") {
    obj.bProp.toFixed() // okay
  } else if (obj.foo === "baz") {
    obj.cProp.toUpperCase() // okay
  } else {
    obj.dProp // okay
  }
}
```

And now things really

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.9.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJICWwALhAE4BmCyAgnkSSbQPYcBcSUF1cgHNWSAL5FR5KnQZIAQkggAPKsAAmUJMwLE2nHkgBEAIxDUjokiYAK1DjF7AArmBM0A3KImEplGvSISADCSqoQGlo6VkgGvKYgWJZ6JPB2Drz8gsBCXno+fjKByAAiYWqa2iwpsVzxAI7OyslsSOrpjkgmXBgQIMDeknqgkLByACoAnjAQdhDqAGLOwPDVMbTL8BSkHMBkUACi4cBQO8AA8rSMADzj5RGVjAB8ABQxJBwmAFa8jAA071qhnGAG0jAYjABdGIASl4ny++yQd10rRI1AgFGc1D2LwRADoDEgALykoEwvKtAo1DYrba7JBUfh476-GHVNFkWhIF6kQ7HU67S43eSvBF-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-KcVx3GoSk2CMthsdkIJQnxv6zCSQEcs6LJhCpxGEdp-x6dKI64mMRrAXazpug4Xp+k+1oYkgmYqhQxQMNCDCcINPCCN5oi6TA+KasSm5qJUCoohYrgoXYgThv+QFheEmo4Va8TVEkrZrn+BSHfEFSmfU7FcSmjgZr0rgDJqGnddMhkLKstkjsqg2Tlq+qvPG30-NO9VNTW16uruxNYuc6qU6NtPUvS+VWuy7PzvDSMrvWt7NoquKXLLp06vFEWmiao7MvxcX89utE62p3qTJIxlBvj7QM9aSabx02avIHmv-JW3OQubgux6L7bg9Dg60vXk6AzO0MLsb66Nsig+mcH4fOtH+tI96n7W2F-6uw8HsQY4GDAcQ4RxjgnLDCAgwvpiCAA)